# How to change specific part of the text in MySQL for selected column?

Tags: mysql, alter

I have a table `news`, it has a column `description`. In the descriptions' column I use `<p>` tags. I want all the `<p>` tags to be changed into `<p itemprop="description">` . How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
UPDATE `news`
SET `description` = REPLACE(description, '<p>', '<p itemprop="description">')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Bad idea. That will scan and *modify* the entire table. At least a `WHERE `description` LIKE '%<p>%'` will avoid modifying rows without paragraphs

Comment: Hi @comcoma if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`select replace(description, '<p>', '<p itemprop="description">') from news`

It is not recommended. My suggestion is to pull the original data from MySQL, then perform the string replacement in the UI or frontend scripts.